# why $dydy=dy^2$ instead of $d^2y^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The first derivative is defined by
$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \lim_{\Delta y\to 0}\frac{x(y+\Delta y)-x(y)}{(y+\Delta y) - y}$$
The second derivative:
$$\frac{d(\frac{dx}{dy})}{dy} = \frac{d}{dy}\frac{dx}{dy} \frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$$

I don't know why $d\,dx = d^2x$ but $dydy=dy^2$ instead of $d^2y^2$

Comment: Perhaps $dy dy = (dy)^2$ and they just omit the parentheses and say $dy^2$ instead?

Comment: All these ds are just symbols, subject to very specific rules, which are intended to be helpful in certain situations. They are **most certainly** not numbers, so there is no reason at all to expect them to behave like numbers. These rulesmare a mixture of tradition, history and math.

Comment: $dy^2$ is another name for $(dy)^2$. When it is operator it becomes $(\frac{d}{dy})^2$

Answer (score 0):

$\def \d{\text{d}}$Let $x$ be an independent variable and then $\d x=\Delta x$. So the differential of an independent variable is a constant and the second differential is zero.

Let it be $\d f\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}f'\d x$ (maybe you have another definition, but still). So $f'=\frac{\d f}{\d x}$.

Then $\d^2 f=\d\d f= f''\d x \d x+f'\d\d x=f''(\d x)^2+f'\d^2 x$
$\d^2 x$ is zero (for independent variable) and $(\d x)^2=\d x^2$ — is just omitting the parentheses.
And we have $f''=\frac{\d^2 f}{\d x^2}$.

---

The other possible way is to think, that $\frac{\d}{\d x}$ is a name for the operator of differentiating with respect to $x$. So $f'=\frac{\d}{\d x}f$ and $f''=\frac{\d}{\d x}\frac{\d}{\d x}f=\frac{\d^2}{\d x^2}f$ (and again omitting the parentheses).